# Spring-kafka migration guide

Tags: spring-kafka

is there some spring-kafka migration guide between 1.3.* and 2.2.* versions? Or at least some changelog, so I know what configuration I need to look into for changes? I wasn't able to find anything in official documentation nor in project's github repository.
Or I can just bump spring-boot and spring-kafka dependencies and it works out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What's new (in 2.2)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#whats-new-part)

(there were a few package and class changes, e.g. `ContainerProperties` was moved).

[Change history 2.1 - 1.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#history).

Aside from the package and class changes, I wouldn't expect any changes needed to user code, unless you want to take advantage of the new features.

If you find any problems, please open a GitHub issue against the project so we can document them.